# the correct notation for sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory, notation

My question is about something formal.

I recently learned about sequences for the first time, and initially, they were denoted by $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ (where each $a_n$ is in $\mathbb{N}\cup \{\infty\}$, or in $\mathbb{R}$ for instance) . But then, in different contexts, I have seen the notations $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$, $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$.

Can I vary the notations as above for writing down sequences? Or is there just one correct way how to do it and everything else is just sloppy notation (and strictly speaking, 'false notation')?

Comment: I think that they are all equivalent. One source of ambiguity can be if $\mathbb N$ starts from $0$ instead of $1$ and this can motivate the form $\{ \ \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$.

Comment: I saw all four of them in different contexts. I guess it depends upon you. But you should stick to one notation at first. And *NEVER EVER* use two different notation for a single object while writing a proof (and in that matter same notation for two different objects in a proof).

Comment: You mean $\mathbf N$ starts from $1$ instead of $0$, I suppose?

Comment: If the usual mathematical reader can understand your notation, it's not sloppy. :) Although, I'd like to point that using $\{\}$ can mean a set, so I prefer simple brackets, but oh well, that's just my 2 cents.

Comment: @Bernard yes, $\mathbb{N}$ starts with 1 (for my question..)

Comment: thank you guys for your comments! I always use only one notation, the one $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$

Answer (score 5):

I would prefer the notation () over {} since {} is used for sets. For instance, if $a_n = (-1)^n$, how would you interpret $\{a_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$, knowing that
$\{a_n \mid n\in \mathbb{N}\} = \{1, -1\}$?

Comment: yes, thank you. I completely agree with you and that's why I do't want to use the notation $\{a_n\}_n$ for sequences.

Answer (score 1):

All of these notations are acceptable for sequences.

In some sense the first one, $(a_n)$, has more emphasis on the order/multiplicity of the elements; purely syntactically, $\{ a_n \}$ could be read as simply the set of elements in the sequence, which involves forgetting about their order/multiplicity.

But because the notation indexes the elements $a_n$ by the natural numbers, which are ordered, the difference doesn't tend to confuse people in the right context.

When writing about your sequences, simply pick some notation and say "let $\{ a_n \}$ be a sequence..." or "let $(a_n)$ be a sequence..." or even "let $a_n$ be a sequence..." (as I tend to do do).